# Observed periodic noise with ASIO sound card in my audio processing application

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, audio-processing, steinberg-asio

I observe noise which shows up periodically (every 5 seconds or so) when i use Asio sound card with the custom built audio processing application visualisation tab which displays the frequency analysis.
The noise is not observed when using a Direct Sound card with the same audio.

I have tried changing the number of channels that are listening to the audio for Asio from 8 to 2 but that doesn't fix the issue!
The sampling rate is 48kHz.( Tweaked it to 44kHz, doesn't fix the issue).

The audio processing application is written in C# and made use of NAudio API.
I've included the images for the waveform in the link:

https://www.sendbig.com/view-files?Id=8fe0ff05-d27e-9ec2-161f-415d923599b7
The first image is the clean signal with no noise and the next image shows the audio along with the noise.
Any inputs on this is appreciated!

Comment: How does the noise look like? Waveform plot, spectrum plot etc

Comment: @Jon Nordby I've added two images of the waveform. 1st image is of the clean signal (380Hz) with no noise. The 2nd image represents the audio signal along with the noise. I cannot attach images in the question since i do not have enough credits here. So, here's the link to the images : https://www.sendbig.com/view-files?Id=8fe0ff05-d27e-9ec2-161f-415d923599b7.